# TypeError. on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, traceback

I try to make a auto response bot for something like automated support everytime i type: `hey i`

The bot outputs this Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

But i have did ctx in de function so i dont know whats wrong with the code
I hope you guys can help me :D

Please help me if you can :D

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    if 'hey' in message.content.lower():
        if 'i' in message.content.lower():
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    if 'test' in message.content.lower():
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on_message` only has 1 input argument (see [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)).

Thus your code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    if 'hey' in message.content.lower():
        if 'i' in message.content.lower():
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    if 'test' in message.content.lower():
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Is incorrect as you specify 2 input arguments, instead of 1 (i.e. you are adding a new required positional argument).

---

So now the question why does it say: `TypeError. on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`?

Well it is very simple, the process that executes the on_message event doesnt have a second input argument for what you call "ctx", as it expected only 1 input argument and not two. Thus throwing this error.

---

Removing ctx will solve the problem, if not then you have other code that is interfering (something you havent showed). Example of how to do this below.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hey' in message.content.lower():
        if 'i' in message.content.lower():
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    if 'test' in message.content.lower():
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: How could i fix that?

Comment: What is that? I said in the last sentence what you needed to do...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) `on_message` only takes 1 argument, being the `message`. To fix this you should just remove `ctx` as a parameter.

```
async def on_message(message):
```

> But i have did ctx in de function so i dont know whats wrong with the code I hope you guys can help me :D

You have an extra parameter `ctx`, which shouldn't be there. As a result, Discord will call this event & never pass `ctx` in there, so the function called will be missing 1 argument, which throws that error. The error does *not* mean you didn't add it to the function signature, but that it wasn't passed *into* the function by whatever called it.

Comment: How could i fix that?

Comment: I told you how to fix it... My answer literally says `to fix it you should {do this}`