# I keep getting a 'missing 1 required positional argument' error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been making a discord autoresponder bot with python and I keep getting an error message.

> TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, msg):
    msg.content = msg.content.lower()
    if "hi" in msg.content:
        await ctx.send ("Hi, I guess")
```

Comment: `on_message()` is getting called with one argument, you're missing a parameter declaration for `msg`

Comment: As stated in the documentation for [on_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message), it only takes one parameter, namely message: `async def on_message(msg)`.

Here you would also use `await msg.channel.send('Hi, I guess')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError. on\_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138000/typeerror-on-message-missing-1-required-positional-argument-ctx)

Comment: Welcome to Stack, Ben. Above is an automated comment when someone marks your question as a duplicate. Please, in the future, it helps reduce the amount of posts on the site when you enter your error into google before posting. This is an important step in debugging as it would help you find answers quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event doesn't have a `ctx` parameter, if you want to reply to the invoking message or send to the same channel, you should use `await msg.channel.send`

Docs

So your event should look more like

```py
async def on_message(msg):
```

Comment: Please flag as a duplicate instead of posting a duplicate answer. This helps cut down on the amount of noise on the site.